# Lifting point to quadratic twisted curve

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

How to lift point to it’s quadratic twisted curve? I use secp256k1. Is the diiscrete log still same? Thanks before

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55298/how-to-explicitly-compute-lifting-of-points-from-an-elliptic-curve-to-a-modular is this helpful?

Comment: From that the point is lifted to rational field not it’s twist in finite fiels. Or maybe you can explain more to me. Thanks